# weird IO operation behavior in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, io

Well I just posted a (semi-like) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452443/jar-file-unexpected-response), and I asked the issue generally, but I've got the issue, and this is a IO problem.

in our program we have to read a file (around 10MB) and decrypt it, I  am using the following class.

```
class FileStream extends InputStream {
  public int available() throws IOException {
    return baseStream.available();
  }
  public boolean markSupported() {
    return false;
  }
  InputStream baseStream;
  byte[] data = new byte[1048576];
  int loopRead = 0;
  int streamSize;
  int dataRead;
  public FileStream(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    this.baseStream = is;
    streamSize = is.available();
  }
  public int read() {
    if (dataRead == streamSize) {
      return -1;/* End of the stream */
    }
    dataRead++;
    if (loopRead == data.length) {
      decrypt();
    }
    return data[loopRead++];
  }
  byte[] tempRead = new byte[4096];// block(smallest) decryption size
  void decrypt() {
    try {
      int r;
      for (int i = 0; i < (data.length / tempRead.length); i++) {
        System.out.print("Data Available: "+baseStream.available());
        r = baseStream.read(tempRead);// read from base stream, ERROR IS HERE!
        System.out.print("Data read: "+r);//not always 4096 in jar file, vary numbers!
        if (r <= 0) {
          return;
        }
        System.arraycopy(tempRead, 0, data, (i * tempRead.length),
            tempRead.length);
      }// end-for
      // /////decrypt the data////////
      loopRead = 0;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
  }
}
```

it **WORKS** when I run it from `eclipse`, but when I generate the JAR file(export) and run it from command line (`java -Xmx1280M -jar app.jar`), it doesn't read the data correct.

The block size(crypt block size) is 4096, so the size of file is dividable by 4096, I really don't know why this happens! it SHOULD read 4096 bytes of data each time, but it doesn't, and always the data availability is more than 4096(as should be).

please help, what are the possible errors or situations would occur here?!

thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you run it? It'd probably help if you didn;t just swallow the exception in the decrypt method. put x.printStackTrace() in the catch block, rebuild, ru-run and see if you get any helpful from that

Comment: There is no exception dear, it just doesn't read the `4096` bytes in each call. @DaveHowes

Comment: This isn't weird behavior. It's exactly the defined behavior. You simply assumed that if it works this way in eclipse, it would work the same way everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic IO. The `read(byte[])` method of `InputStream` isn't guaranteed to read the whole byte array full of data. That's why it returns the number of actual bytes read.

`DataInputStream` does have a `readFully()` method that will fill the array completely.

Comment: So why it works without any problem when I run it from eclipse? and why the data availability is always more than requested read?

Comment: Because. That's why. The contract for read(byte[]) defines that it can read up to byte[].length bytes, and you need to code accordingly. If you ignore the definition, you'll run into situations like the one you're currently in. It doesn't matter if it works in eclipse, it's not guaranteed to work anywhere the way you coded it.